# How to get which program executed the EXE by C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process

If a.exe has been run and called by another program b.exe (uses shellexecute API or Process), is there a way to get the program b.exe path or process ID by C#? Thanks.

Comment: If you're planning/hoping to make some kind of security decision based on this, then the answer in general is no. If not, what *goal* are you trying to achieve by obtaining this information?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I want to kill a adware a.exe but it keep being called once killed. I don't know what EXE file runs it.